# When params from function creator are available in created functions?

Tags: javascript, function, debugging

I have such a function creator:

```
var creator = function(param) {return function(){
  debugger;
}}
```

Now, when I create function:

```
var f = creator(123);
```

and run it:

```
f();
```

I am not able to get `param` from debugging mode.

In this version of creator:

```
var creator = function(param) {return function(){
  var param = param;
  debugger;
}}
```

`param` in debugging mode is `undefined`, but in this situation:

```
var creator = function(param) {return function(){
  var a = param;
  debugger;
}}
```

both `a` and `param` values equals `123`.

What is the rule saying when params from creators are avaiable in created functions and when they aren't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, when I create function:
>
> ```
> var f = creator(123);
> ```
>
> and run it:
>
> ```
> f();
> ```
>
> I am not able to get param from debugging mode.

That's just because the JavaScript engine saw that you didn't use `param` and optimized it out. If you'd actually used it, you'd've been able to see it in the debugger within `f`.

> In this version of creator:
>
> ```
> var creator = function(param) {return function(){
>   var param = param;
>   debugger;
> }}
> ```
>
> `param` in debugging mode is `undefined`

That's because you've *shadowed* the parameter with a local variable, and the default value of a local variable is `undefined`.

> but in this situation:
>
> ```
> var creator = function(param) {return function(){
>   var a = param;
>   debugger;
> }}
> ```
>
> both `a` and `param` values equals 123.

Because now that you're actually using `param`, the JavaScript engine didn't optimize it away. (And of course, `a` is a local variable you've set to the same value as the parameter.)

Answer (score 2):

**They are available if you don't create any variables with duplicated names**. In first case you use the same name(starting from root to down), which overrides the `param`.
Parameters are also variables. Let's look. When you pass a parameter consider that it is going to be declared like this

```
function(){
    var param = 123: // 123 is passed.
    return function() {
       ...
    } 
}
```

And then when you have done `var param = param` it does a thing like this.

```
function(){
    var param = 123: // 123 is passed.
    return function() {
       var param; // here you redefine param, which shadows the upper one, so param is now undefined
       param = param;
    }      
}
```

And so why you get `undefined` with same names and correct values with different names.